# How do I stay DRY with HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have HAML installed with Rails. I'm trying to extend the functionality of it by making snippet-templates. For example I have this general image structure:

```
- @images.each do |image|
  .image
    %a{ :href => image.target }
      = image_tag image.url
    %a{ :href => edit_image_path(image) }
      Edit
```

or at least something to that effect. What I would like to do is clean it up so that I can say:

```
- @images.each do |image|
  = render 'snippet/image' image
```

How can I accomplish this semantically? Obviously, I could declare a variable in my snippet and assign it before rendering, but that seems super-lazy. Is there an example I could see that shows both the snippet and how it's rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`render` can take a `:collection` option, like so:

```
= render :partial => "image", :collection => @images
```

See section 3.4.5 Rendering Collections in the [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) guide, which says:

> the partial will be inserted once for each member in the collection ... the partial [will] have access to the member of the collection ... via a variable named after the partial

Comment: I forgot about that! Much better solution than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
- @images.each do |image|
  render :partial => 'snippet/image', :locals => { :image => image }
```

It's semantic alright, although a bit verbose.